# Troubleshooting "Connection Refused" Error in Apache Spark Standalone Mode Deployment

Tags: apache-spark

I'm currently exploring Apache Spark and need to deploy it in standalone mode. My setup consists of one master server and one worker node. To set up this configuration, I've been following the official documentation

Here are the steps I've followed:

- I added the worker node's IP address to the master node's workers file located at `/opt/spark/conf/workers` in the format `<worker node username>@<worker-node-IP>`.
- Both the master and worker nodes are on the same network, and I've configured SSH so that the master machine can access each of the worker machines.
- To start the master machine, I ran the command `./sbin/start-master.sh` from the Spark directory on the master machine. It ran successfully and generated a Spark URL in the format `spark://<hostname>:7077`.
- Once the master node was started, I attempted to start the worker nodes using the Spark URL with the command `./sbin/start-workers.sh spark://<hostname>:7077`.
- However, when I checked if the worker node was added via the web UI at `localhost:8080` after running the above command on the master node, I couldn't see the worker node.
- While running `./sbin/start-workers.sh spark://<hostname>:7077` on the master machine, it created a log file on the worker node, and I found the following error in that log file: `java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname>`.

To resolve this error, I added the hostname to the hosts file located at `/etc/hosts` in the following format: `<IP of the master node> <hostname of the master node>`.

After making this setup change, I attempted to run both the master and worker nodes as mentioned above, but I still encountered the following error message in the worker node log file: `Connection refused: <hostname of the master node>/<IP of the master node>:7077`.

I've already verified that the master node is running on the IP and port mentioned in the error message, and I've also disabled the firewall on the master node machine as a final troubleshooting step. However, I'm still encountering the "Connection refused" error.

If anyone has a solution or further suggestions on how to resolve this issue, please let me know.